# Channel-style routing on Altera FPGAs

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, routing

[A Tutorial on FPGA Routing](http://www.gstitt.ece.ufl.edu/courses/eel4720_5721/reading/Routing.pdf) claims that there are two different FPGA routing styles; channel-style ASIC routing and island style routing:

> Academic research has adopted as FPGA architecture a simplified
> version of the island style model from Xilinx. The main reason is
> that FPGA market share is divided in mainly three companies: Xilinx
> with the highest share has an average presence of roughly half of
> the total market 3, Altera has roughly one-third, and Actel has
> one-six of the market. From these three companies Actel and Altera
> have respectively solved their routing problems by adapting channel-
> style ASIC routing algorithms [1] or over assigning routing
> resources [2]; so the active research area left to academia is the
> island style architecture from Xilinx FPGAs, nevertheless this is an
> important architecture as it is responsible of half of the entire
> FPGAs production [3] on the market.

The text provides an extremely good overview of island style routing,
but not much on what channel-style ASIC routing is or how it works on
Altera FPGAs. So can anyone explain how channel-style ASIC routing on
FPGAs work? The references in the text doesn't provide much clude.